# Using a variable in strings.xml in Eclipse/Android

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, variables

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_selectDate"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="@string/date"/>
```

I need this title to be variable to the selected date

Comment: What do you mean with "Let's say I have a variable string "date" in some other class, can I use this in my strings.xml file?"? A variable 'date' and the resource 'date'  have  nothing in common.

Answer (score 1):

just try below code for get your string from your project resource:

```
String date= getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.date);
```

Comment: I have my date set in another class, I want to use this in the strings.xml file to use it in my Android Menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

If it array of String then use,

```
String[] some_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.your_string_array);
```

Or else

```
String date= getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.date);
```

Comment: So I leave my string.xml empty?
    <string name="date"></string>

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
String res_date = Context.getResources().getString (R.string.date)
```

Please see the android developer guide  [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

Answer (score 0):

Leave the string name field empty in your layout. then in your activity write the following:

```
menu_selectDate.setText(YourDate);
```